# Importar dados de um TXT sem tabulação

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, txt

Ola

Tenho conhecimentos basicos no assunto e preciso da ajuda de voces para resolver um problema - se necessário, estou até disposto a pagar pela ajuda pq sei que talvez possa ser algo mais complexo de se fazer.

Eu recebi de um cliente um arquivo texto em linha - sem tabulação. São dezenas de dados agrupados em DUAS linhas - na verdade sao 6 linhas ao todo - mas os dados que preciso estão em duas - as outras 4 linhas sao só controles.

Existe alguma forma de retirar esses dados sem tabulação? Eu tenho o layout do arquivo - exatamente o que cada linha se refere - e a posição em caracteres de cada informação.

Antes eu recebi esse arquivo com UMA LINHA (tinha outras de controle q era descartadas) - porem TABULADO - e jogava esse TXT no EXCEL - que identificava as tabulações - e abria pra mim a opção de colocar LARGURA FIXA - eu digitava o caracter final de cada coluna - e pronto! Importava tudo certinho.

[image: EXCEL > IMPORTATAR TXT COM TABUALAÇÃO]

Agora o arquivo nao esta com tabulação e tem DUAS LINHAS de informação - tecnicamente imagino que seria a mesma coisa se o arquivo estivesse tabulado - porem, nao sei se pelo fato de ter DUAS LINHAS de dados nao adiantaria ser tabulado.

De qq forma existe uma forma de importar os dados do arquivo?

O segmento do arquivo txt é assim:

01E0032470000005007850001000456590770RF513100000027104042022040420230100002108714005131

02E003247000000500785000100045659                                             J00776574000660000000000999999999901                                             102                 XXXXXX              Rio de Janeiro      20221160RJ0000000000005          00.00-0-00   11111111111        0101200001Brasil    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                   F0000999999999983NAO INFORMADO                                               S/N       NA        NAO INFORMADO       NA                  20221160NA            5          00.00-0-01RG 11111111111   SSPSP00000000BRASIL

08E0032470000005007850001000456590000018500010004565910004565904042022                              43.0000000000000000.00                                                                                0020221160       NAO INFORMADO                                     S/N                                                        NA                            NAO INFORMADO                 100006633244754XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX               0000000001XXXXX XXX 4 XX 32XX XXXX                0000000007XXXXX XXX 4 XX 32XX XXXX                0000000001XXXXX XXX 4 XX 32XX XXXX                0000000001XXXXX XXX 4 XX 32XX XXXX

com mais 3 linhas similares a primeira - as linhas que preciso retirar os dados sao as que começam com 02 e 08.

É possivel importar os dados assim ou o cliente precisa me enviar ele tabulado?

obrigado!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Tenta abrir o TXT no Excel, delimite a coluna A para exibir apenas os 2 primeiros caracteres. Depois aplica um filtro, selecionando e removendo apenas o que é de interesse.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Oi @Siegraim - primeiro obrigado por dedicar uma parte do seu tempo em me ajudar. Vou tentar fazer isso - alias, ja estava quebrando a cabeça com isso - o problema é que diferente do arquivo tabulado - qdo importo esse em linha - o excel so deixa "CARREGAR" o arquivo - o tabulado tinha os controles de dados q postei na imagem (ai escolhia posicao e pronto!) - aqui eu so posso CARREGAR.. e dai vai pra uma janela de transformação de dados. ai eu recebo todas as linhas. baseado na sua dica (que ja é uma luz no fim do tunel, sinal q tem soluçao..rs) - estou tentando resolver. valeu!!